# How to make v-menu keyboard accessible

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, accessibility

Vuetify 5.10 and Vue 2.6.14.

I know the Vuetify documentation says:

> By default, v-menu components are detached and moved to the root of your application. In order to properly support inserting dynamic content into the DOM, you must use the attach prop. This will ensure that focus transfers from the activator to the content when pressing the tab key.

But they don't provide any example and I tried it and I couldn't make it work so I ended up not using it and just having a method that shows and hides my dropdown on click(it works but It sounds possible with v-menu).

Here is what I tried, this is not keyboard accessible:

```
   <v-menu>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }"> -->
        <div v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" class="nearby-trigger">
          <toggle-button
            phrase="Location"
            standalone
            attach="#nearbyLocation"
          ></toggle-button>
        </div>
      </template>

      <v-card id="nearbyLocation">
        <v-container>
          <v-row>
            <v-col>
              <v-text-field hide-details placeholder="Area Code"></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-card>
    </v-menu>
```

Update:
To give more explanation on the issue:
The problem is that v-menu injects everything inside at the end of the DOM tree so let's say I have a header with my v-menu then main and then footer, well I can reach that menu via keyboard after the footer so I have to tab all the way through till after the footer. In conclusion, it appears in the right place but isn't in the right tab order(yes I've tried tabindex)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you elaborate more? what is `not keyboard accessible? What is expected and what is actual currently?

Comment: Are you able to provide a generated HTML page (i.e., not just the Vue.js snippet) with your v-menu, so we can test it on our own machines?

Comment: Yes! Keyboard accessibility encompasses many things but the two biggest thing are can you use the keyboard to get to the item and second is it where you expect it. So here the problem is that v-menu inject everything inside at the end of the DOM tree so lets say I have a header with my v-menu then main and then footer, well I can reach that menu after the footer so I have to tab all the way through till after the footer. It's a known issue but I can't seem to make it work with their work around. @ThatsME

Comment: @George, I'm sorry I'm not allowed to share the entirety of the code but nothing is changing the inherent issue with v-menu .

Comment: @Oci without the generated HTML it's going to be difficult to help answer your question, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @dick.ey for helping me with this answer

The solution was to figure out attach. By default v-menu is attached at the root(https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VMenu/VMenu.ts)

You can attach v-menu to a specific place and that would be the parent of where v-menu is. Since I didn't want to disturb the order or css I opted to create a div parent container and I attached it to that.

```js
<div id="searchMenu">
 <v-menu attach="#searchMenu">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }"> -->
        <div v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" class="nearby-trigger">
          <toggle-button
            phrase="Location"
            standalone
            attach="#nearbyLocation"
          ></toggle-button>
        </div>
      </template>

      <v-card id="nearbyLocation">
        <v-container>
          <v-row>
            <v-col>
              <v-text-field hide-details placeholder="Area Code"></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-card>
    </v-menu>
</div>
```

The div in that code will always exist while my card now gets added at the end of that div rather than the end of my root which would consist of a footer which is terrible for keyboard accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

This sandbox example seems to be working when using tab to get to the v-menu button and the arrow keys to navigate between the items:

```js
<template>
  <div class="text-xs-center">
    <v-menu offset-y>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-btn color="primary" dark v-on="on" id="menuButton"> Dropdown </v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-tile
          v-for="(item, index) in items"
          :key="index"
          @click="onMenuItemClick(item)"
          tabindex="1"
        >
          <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      { title: "List Item 1" },
      { title: "List Item 2" },
      { title: "List Item 3" },
      { title: "List Item 4" },
    ],
    menuButton: undefined,
  }),

  methods: {
    onMenuItemClick(item) {
      console.log(`${item.title} clicked`);
      // manually set focus back to the button on click.
      this.menuButton.focus();
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.menuButton = document.getElementById("menuButton");
  },
};
</script>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-sandbox-32bw5r?file=/src/components/Menu.vue